# Is Apache POI XDGF also read only

Tags: apache-poi, visio

I read that the HDGF implementation is read only here:
http://poi.apache.org/diagram/

It says:

> Currently, HDGF provides a low-level, read-only api for accessing Visio documents. It also provides a way to extract the textual content from a file.

I need to determine if the XDGF implementation also is read only. The docs don't mention it. Has anyone experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point into XDGF is `XmlVisioDocument`. If you look at the top of the [XDGF XmlVisioDocument JavaDocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xdgf/usermodel/XmlVisioDocument.html), you'll see the following:

> This is your high-level starting point for working with Visio XML documents (.vsdx). **Currently, only read support has been implemented**, and the API is not mature and is subject to change

(Highlighting mine)

.

As for why this isn't on the website... There is currently [an outstanding Apache "Help Wanted" task for improving the XDGF documentation](https://helpwanted.apache.org/task.html?840a9a250c5eb684a21e32a379e9b6ce70797375), in case this inspires you to help :)